# Jstl: using scriptlet inside custom tags

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I use custom tags in order to create some kind master page (template).
The construction is following:

```
// Template
<%@ tag description="master" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ attribute name="js" fragment="true" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <jsp:invoke fragment="js" />
</head>
<body>
</html>

// Page
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>   
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %> 
<t:master>
    <jsp:attribute name="js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/javascript/administration/customers.js" />"></script>
    </jsp:attribute>
</t:master>
```

It works fine until I try to use the common solution for disabling browser-side caching of javascript by adding random string to the end of js filename:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/javascript/administration/customers.js" />?<%= new java.util.Date().getTime() %>"></script>
```

It fails with

> Scripting elements ( <%!, <jsp:declaration, <%=,
>   <jsp:expression, <%, <jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.

exception

How can I implement such solution? Thank you

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive: it says you to [not use scriptlets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, but I understand what error says... The question was different

Comment: The question title has no relation with the question content to begin with...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, my mistake. Fixed

Comment: Based on your fix, you must already know that you should not use scriptlets. The technology forbid this (and is doing the right job). It would be better to rethink your design in order of EL/JSTL instead of scriptlets usage.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know that and definetely agree with you. My question regarding this particluar case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild suggestion :-)

Use a usebean to generate a new Date object in the request scope. Each request would then result in a new Date object creation. This will be reused through the whole request.

```
 <jsp:useBean id="uniqueDate" class="java.util.Date" scope="request"/>
```

Then call the getTime() method on the date object (as suggested in comment).

```
${uniqueDate.time}
```

Comment: BalusC meant that instead of using `<jsp:useBean>` you could use `<c:set>` to maintain pure JSTL/EL code and just call the variable by using `${uniqueDate.time}`.

Comment: No, I don't think that is at all what he means. Note that the bottom half of my answer is edited and replaced by the content in his comment. Also, please explain how <c:set> can replace <jsp:useBean>?